# Wedge product of two 2-covectors

Tags: vector-spaces, exterior-algebra

This is an exercise from Tu's book on manifolds, which I am self-studying from. It is a rather simple computational problem, but I wanted to verify my solution first before proceeding with the book. The problem asks for $f, g \in A_2(V)$, to compute $f \wedge g$.

My solution is
$$\begin{align}(f \wedge g)(v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4) = &f(v_1, v_2)g(v_3,v_4) - f(v_1, v_3)g(v_2, v_4) \\+ &f(v_2, v_3)g(v_1, v_4) - f(v_2, v_4)g(v_1, v_3) \\+ &f(v_3, v_4)g(v_1, v_2)+ f(v_1,v_4)g(v_2, v_3).\end{align}$$

I know yes and no questions are frowned upon here, so I apologize in advance, but I would like to ask if this solution is correct.

Comment: For starters, the LHS should be $(f\wedge g)(v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4)$. You seem to be missing a number of the $4!$ permutations, don't you? Since 5 doesn't divide 24, your number of terms is particularly suspicious.

Comment: Yes you are right, I forgot to add the argument for $f \wedge g$ on the LHS. For the constant in front of the RHS, shouldn't it be $2!2! = 4$ as opposed to $4!$?

Comment: @TedShifrin In Tu's book he defines the wedge product by considering only those permutations that preserve the increasing order of indices, $(f \wedge g)(v_1, \ldots, v_{k+\ell}) = \sum_{(k, \ell) \text{ shuffles } \sigma} (sgn(\sigma))f(v_{\sigma(1)},\ldots, v_{\sigma(k)})g(v_{\sigma(k+1)},\ldots, v_{\sigma(k+\ell)})$, so he seems to have no coefficient in front.

Comment: @TedShifrin Also I noticed you are correct in that I am forgetting one extra factor, I have included it in my edit.

Comment: Note now that $6\cdot 2!\cdot 2! = 4!$, so it looks good.

Comment: @TedShifrin Awesome, thank you!

Comment: I get the same solution, though it does surprise me as for some reason I was expecting 3 negative terms and 3 positive terms.